# Do any mutex implementations allow locking from one thread and unlocking in another

Tags: multithreading

In a discussion elsewhere someone has proposed that there may be platforms on which a mutex could be unlocked from a thread other than that which locked it.

I'm unconvinced, but my experience is limited to platforms where this is never allowed; are there any platforms that allow it?

If there are, how would one possibly utilise such a facility? If you can no longer assume that a mutex remains locked between the LOCK and UNLOCK steps that seems to me to defeat the point. Are there scenarios where it must be done and can be done safely with care?

Comment: In my opinion, if this is allowed, then this is no longer a Mutex but something else and as you stated, it defeats the purpose of the mechanism making it useless.

Comment: A mutex having thread affinity is a very big deal.  You are just using the wrong synchronization primitive if you want to unlock in another thread.  Every platform implements the other one that doesn't have affinity, semaphore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no there isn't a shared mutex between threads like this.  As that would defeat the purpose of a mutex.  If it's something you really want, then you can use a `Semaphore(1)`.  Semaphores allow non-acquiring threads to release the acquired count.